# Не( )много и не( )мало

Tags: наречия, не-plus-adverb

Примерный диалог:

> - Как дела? Много работы?
> - Не( )много и не( )мало.

Как правильно пишутся наречия в этом случае?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пишется раздельно.

Д. Э. Розенталь, «Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация»
Раздел 17. Правописание частиц,  [§ 61. Частица ***не*** с наречиями](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81):

> 3. Пишется   р а з д е л ь н о   частица ***не*** с наречиями на ***-о***, если имеется или подразумевается противопоставление: *живут **не богато**, а бедно; обычно ехали **не быстро** и **не медленно**; **не часто** возникает подобная ситуация; **не скоро** ещё вскроется река; **не случайно** он завёл этот разговор; **не вечно** будет природа хранить свои тайны от человека; **не сладко** жилось переселенцам на первых порах; Говоря честно, **не много** найдётся людей, которые не испытывают неприятного чувства при виде пауков.*

Пример «*обычно ехали **не быстро** и **не медленно***» полностью соответствует ситуации в вашем диалоге, так что ***не*** там следует писать раздельно:

> — Как дела? Много работы?
> — **Не много** и **не мало**.